# How to merge column instance_name from instance table and status from rman_backup_job_details table using UNION?

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I need to merge column from two different tables in ORACLE 12c database using UNION. Is it possible?

```
select instance_name from v$instance

select input_type, status, start_time, end_time from V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS
```

I need output like this

```
INSTANCE_NAME    INPUT_TYPE    STATUS              START_TIME
---------------- ------------- ----------------------- --------------
END_TIME
--------------
 orcl        DB FULL       COMPLETED           08/03/17 18:39
 08/03/17 18:41
```

The above output should get using UNION keyword by multiple select query is it possible? . Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Pls use only the relevant product tags, not any random you can think of!

Comment: And the output looks more like a join than a union.

Comment: Add some sample table data (a few rows per table), and the expected result. (All as formatted text.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simple  [CROSS JOIN](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqljcrossjoin.html). See below:

```
SELECT distinct   
       a.instance_name,
       jb.input_type,
       jb.status,
       jb.start_time,
       jb.end_time
  FROM V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS jb 
  CROSS JOIN v$instance a
```

Comment: Thank you it working. But i need to remove duplicate header while it write to txt file or html file .. In the query itself Is it possible to remove duplicate header?

Comment: Yes.. You can put a `distinct` in the select clause. See updated

Comment: *INSTANCE_NAME  INPUT_TYPE    STATUS         START_TIM END_TIME*
---------------- ------------- ----------------------- --------- ---------
orcl   DB FULL       COMPLETED        25-JUL-17 25-JUL-17

*INSTANCE_NAME  INPUT_TYPE    STATUS         START_TIM END_TIME*
---------------- ------------- ----------------------- --------- ---------
orcledb   DB FULL       COMPLETED        31-JUL-17 31-JUL-17
orcledb   DB FULL       COMPLETED        01-AUG-17 01-AUG-17

Comment: I need to remove duplicate header is 
INSTANCE_NAME INPUT_TYPE STATUS START_TIM END_TIME

Comment: Well you can do `set heading off` but then it would not bring the first heading all well. So you need to write the header once by some means